# Ploytly remove ticks with no data

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I've scratched my head over this for too long. I've tried to update the ticks and their labels, but that creates another issue of loosing accuracy, and having too many tick labels show making the axes very clustered.

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0): 10,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 15, 0): 20,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0): 30,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 45, 0): 40,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0): 40,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 13, 15, 0): 30,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 13, 30, 0): 20,
    datetime(2022, 1, 1, 13, 45, 0): 10,

}

df = pd.Series(data)

# Plot line graph
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df.values,
        mode='lines',
    )
)

# Update the axies
fig.update_yaxes(title="Value")
fig.update_xaxes(title="Date")

# Update the overall figure layout
fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "Title",
        'x': 0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
)
fig.show()
```

and it generate the following chart. [image]

## Issue

The chart shows a straight line from 11:00 to 13:00, but as per the `data` there are no values for it. I'd like for that to not be plotted, and those ticks to just not show up.

## I've tried.

To remove the ticks, by converting the date to indexed numbers, and then relabelling them accordingly, however this created another issue of each tick showing the label, and i loose accuracy. IE: If the data is 3 months, then the ticks will show only date every so date, but when i zoom into one day, it relabels them to times for that day. however with my solution to re index and label, every tick has the label making it impossible to read.

### Packages need to run the above code.

```
pip install dash pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out like 20mins after asking this question.

I had to update the following two lines

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
        x=df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), # Convert the datetime to my desired format
        y=df.values,
        mode='lines',
    )
)
```

## AND

```
fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': "Title",
        'x': 0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'
    },
    xaxis=dict(type="category") # Not sure what it does, will update once i know.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution works for me, but I am not sure if this help solve your problem.

You can just skip the ticks without any data by setting the parameter `ticklabelstep` of `update_xaxes`.

The complete code: `fig.update_xaxes(ticklabelstep=1)`.